# How to make html5 date field in search toolbar to respect column width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid is used with Bootstrap 3.
Toolbar search contains html5 date field.
Date field width is bigger than column width.
If column is resized, date field width is still bigger.

How to fix this so that date field width in toolbar search is not wider than its column and will not become wider than column on resize ?

Testcase is in http://jsfiddle.net/yt6L6p61/

```
var serverResponse = {
        "page": "1",
        "records": "3",
        "rows": [
            { "Id": "1", IsActive:'2015-01-09' },
            { "Id": "2", IsActive:'2015-01-05' },
            { "Id": "3", IsActive:'2015-01-21' }
        ]
    },
initDateHtmlSearch = function (elem){
  $(elem).attr("type", "date");
},

DateTemplate = {
    sorttype: 'date',
    formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {
        srcformat: "Y-m-d",
        reformatAfterEdit: true
    },
    editoptions: {
        maxlength: 10,
        size: 10,
//        dataInit: initDateEdit
    },
    editable: true,
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
        dataInit: initDateHtmlSearch,
        size: 10,
        attr: { size: 10 }
    }
},

    $grid = $("#categorysummary");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse)
    },
    colNames: ["Id", "Active", 'Second'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', hidden: true },
        { name: 'IsActive', template: DateTemplate, width:90
        },
        { name: 'Second', width:85
        }

        ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: 'Id',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    viewrecords: true
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="categorysummary"></table>
</div>
```

Note that second column in testcase behaves as expected: it is not wider than its column width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/10qwgejj/4/ which have the following code

```js
var serverResponse = {
        "page": "1",
        "records": "3",
        "rows": [
            { "Id": "1", IsActive: "2015-01-09" },
            { "Id": "2", IsActive: "2015-01-05" },
            { "Id": "3", IsActive: "2015-01-21" }
        ]
    },    
    dateTemplate = {
        sorttype: "date",
        formatter: "date",
        formatoptions: {
            srcformat: "Y-m-d",
            reformatAfterEdit: true
        },
        editoptions: {
            maxlength: 10,
            size: 10
        },
        editable: true,
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"],
            size: 10,
            clearSearch: false,
            attr: { size: 10, type: "date", style: "width:11em;" }
        }
    },
    $grid = $("#categorysummary");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse)
    },
    colNames: ["Active", "Second"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "IsActive", template: dateTemplate, width: 125 },
        { name: "Second", width: 85 }
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: "Id",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    viewrecords: true
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

and additional CSS rule, which fix the problem existing because of the usage of Bootstrap CSS

```css
.ui-search-table input[type=date] {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

**UPDATE:** One can resize the `input[type=date]` after resizing the column. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/10qwgejj/8/ which use additionally

```js
resizeStop: function (newWidth, iCol) {
    var colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (colModel[iCol].name === "IsActive") {
        $("#gs_IsActive").width(newWidth - 7); // - padding
    }
}
```

Comment: If first column is resized to small width, date search field in toolbar still overlaps with next column toolbar search field. How to fix this so that date search field will not overlap with next column search field ?

Comment: In answer `$(elem).attr("type", "date")` was removed. This causes date element to disappear in advanced search form.

Comment: @Andrus: The demo don't use advanced searching. It's just an example of usage `filterToolbar`. You should of cause modify the code if you use it in more common case (editing, advanced searching and so on). To reduce the minimal column width you can specify `autoResizing: { minColWidth: 125 }` in the column. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/10qwgejj/6/. It's important to use the latest code of free jqGrid.

Comment: `minColwidth: 125` disables resizing to smaller widths. How to allow resizing to smaller widths and clip right part of date input element or decrease its width if column width is small?

Comment: @Andrus: I think that one can't do this. One can just reduce the minimal width on the column.

Comment: It can be done by changing `style: "width:11em;"`  in demo. How to set this value automatically from column width and after column is resized ?

Comment: @Andrus: I don't understand what you mean. You had problem with CSS conflict between default Bootstrap CSS and jqGrid. I posted you that the problem could be fixed by usage `.ui-search-table input[type=data] {line-height: normal;}` to restore original line height. The width of **date input should be fixed** because of the fixed format of data `mm/dd/yyyy`. The column width should be not smaller to be able to display the date input from the filter toolbar.

Comment: Question was about fixing width but answer fixes height. In application jqgrid search toolbar height is set to same as date field height in bootstrap. Fixing height is not important. How to make date field visible part never wider than column widht ? Question is updated with expected result description and image

Comment: @Andrus: We have different imagination how the filter toolbar should look like. I wrote you that I don't see any sense in displaying the searching toolbar with not full input having type=date.

Comment: Date search may used rarely. In locale dd.mm.yyyy year is last in value. Users like to shrink date column so that only day or day and month are visible. This saves space so that more really useful information is displayed. For search date column can enlarged temporary. Sometimes only day or day and months needs changed for new search. In this case new day/month can entered from keyboard and search performed by enter using narrow search field. This is standard behaviour for other elements in search toolbar. It looks native that date element behaves like others. Current overlap is ugly.

Comment: @Andrus: The reason of the overlap - the behavior of `<input type=date>`. You can set the width of the input field explicitly in `resizeStop`: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/10qwgejj/7/

Comment: Fiddle contains typo `type=data`, but it looks like it solves the issue, style is not needed? This occurs with jquery ui datepicker also, so date input type is not an reason. Anyway, it looks like fiddle fixes the issue. Thank you.

Comment: How to remove hard-coded column name from resizeStop ? All date columns have dateTemplate. I tried `colModel[iCol].template === "dateTemplate"` but in this case column is not resized.

Comment: @Andrus: there are a thousand different ways, depend on your goals. For example you can get the value of `type` attribute and compare there with `"date"`: `if ($("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(colModel[iCol].name)).attr("type") === "date") {...}`

Comment: Goal is to make date column resizable like other columns. I tried your suggestion using http://jsfiddle.net/10qwgejj/10/ and looks like this works. Thank you.

Comment: On initial grid load and maybe on autoresize  resizeStop is not called and date columns are still too wide. How to set proper width on initial load also ?

Comment: I updated question and added image. It shows that search toolbar is totally out of order if date search is used.

Comment: @Andrus: You should just set the width of all `.ui-search-table input[type=date]` to the width of the corresponding column: `$(".ui-search-table input[type=date]").each(function() { $(this).css("width", $(this).closest("th.ui-th-column").width() + "px"); });`. See http://jsfiddle.net/10qwgejj/10/

Comment: this fiddle does not have this statement. Is last fiddle link correct ?

Comment: It does not work on autoresize. After double click in Active column right border column autoresizes but search field keeps its width. How to fix this ?

Comment: I posted this as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577349/how-to-set-date-search-toolbar-field-width-on-autoresize