# How to set date search toolbar field width on autoresize

Tags: jquery, css, html, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I*m looking for a way to set date toolbar search field width on autoresize.

I tried code from

[How to make html5 date field in search toolbar to respect column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475094/how-to-make-html5-date-field-in-search-toolbar-to-respect-column-width)

comment:

```
var serverResponse = {
        "page": "1",
        "records": "3",
        "rows": [
            { "Id": "1", IsActive: "2015-01-09" },
            { "Id": "2", IsActive: "2015-01-05" },
            { "Id": "3", IsActive: "2015-01-21" }
        ]
    },    
    dateTemplate = {
        sorttype: "date",
        formatter: "date",
        formatoptions: {
            srcformat: "Y-m-d",
            reformatAfterEdit: true
        },
        autoResizing: { minColWidth: 50 },
        autoResizable: true,
        width: 100,
        editoptions: {
            maxlength: 10,
            size: 10
        },
        editable: true,
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"],
            size: 10,
            clearSearch: false,
            attr: { size: 10, type: "date", style: "width:11em;" }
        }
    },
    $grid = $("#categorysummary");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse)
    },
    colNames: ["Active", "Second"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "IsActive", template: dateTemplate },
        { name: "Second", width: 85 }
    ],
    resizeStop: function (newWidth, iCol) {
        var colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if ($("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(colModel[iCol].name)).attr("type") === "date") {

                $("#gs_IsActive").width(newWidth - 7); // - padding
        }
    },
    jsonReader: {
        id: "Id",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    viewrecords: true
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
$(".ui-search-table input[type=date]").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", $(this).closest("th.ui-th-column").width() + "px");
});
```

css:

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="categorysummary"></table>
</div>
```

See fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/10qwgejj/13/

After double clicking in column separator line in Active column header search element with is too big and column border disappears from search toolbar.

[image: overlap]
To set  search field width on autoresize ?

Andrus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/a2d1a379f6f6aa634e1f6b54b71f2e6ff464c4d4)) new callback `afterResizeDblClick` and new event jqGridAfterResizeDblClick, which makes the solution very easy.

It uses the following code

```
var adjustSearchingDateField = function (cmName, newWidth) {
    var $searchingField = $("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(cmName));
    if ($searchingField.attr("type") === "date") {
        $searchingField.width(newWidth - 7); // - padding
    }
};

...
resizeStop: function (newWidth, iCol) {
    var colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    adjustSearchingDateField(colModel[iCol].name, newWidth);
},
afterResizeDblClick: function (options) {
    adjustSearchingDateField(options.cmName, options.cm.width);
},
...
```

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/10qwgejj/14/

Comment: Latest jqgrid adds jqgrid id to toolbar id field.  How to fix this code so that it works with latest jqgrid if `idMode` is not specified ?

Comment: @Andrus: Read [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#main-new-features-and-improvements-implemented-in-the-version-4131) to the new version. **The BREAKING CHANGES** part described `idMode` option of `filterToolbar` with 3 different values.