# How to show filter toolbar only if jqgrid has more than 20 rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid if populated from remote json data.
Code

```
$(function () {
    $grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        defaultSearch: 'cn'
    });
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475094/how-to-make-html5-date-field-in-search-toolbar-to-respect-column-width
    $(".ui-search-table input[type=date]").each(function () {
        $(this).css("width", $(this).closest("th.ui-th-column").width() + "px");
    });
```

is used to create filter toolbar.

Somethimes grid is empty or contains few rows. In this case filter toolbar is confusing. For empty grid users think that entering data to this row adds new row. This confuses users.

How to show filter toolbar only if grid contains more than 20 rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the value of `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "records")` inside of `loadComplete`. It's the total number of records in the grid. If the value will be less as 20 rows then you can call `toggleToolbar` to hide/show the filter toolbar.

jqGrid don't have currently any direct way which you can use to test, where the toolbar is visible currently. You can use `this.ftoolbar` (`$("#grid")[0].ftoolbar`) to test whether the filter toolbar already exist and `$(this.grid.hDiv).find("tr.ui-search-toolbar").css("display") === "none"` to test whether the filter toolbar is already hidden.